# rake db:migrate fails with Mysql2::Error: Row size too large

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I was running a rake db:migrate for my rails which failed with the following error:

```
==  AddColumnsToSavedSearch: migrating ========================================
-- add_column(:saved_searches, :search_param1, :string, {:limit=>1000})
   -> 0.0574s
-- add_column(:saved_searches, :search_param2, :string, {:limit=>1000})
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs: ALTER TABLE `saved_searches` ADD `search_param2` varchar(1000)
```

This migration runs fine on my other system which has the same configuration (same OS and DB).

My MySQL DB version is Server version: 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu).

Any help is appreciated.

Please do let me know if you need any information.

Thanks

Comment: What is the row size in bytes for that table, before you run the migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the issue, but generally the string datatype is used for smaller quantities of text. I believe it uses the VARCHAR(255) type for MySQL. Try changing the datatype to text. There may be some conflict in attempting to limit the columns to a size larger than string can support.

Comment: I'm pretty sure exactly that is the issue. ;)

Comment: Thank you. I changed the migration file and removed the limits and this time the migration went through. Appreciate your help.